# PyQt4 connect signals between classes

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am new in gui programming with pyQt.
I have setup a simple gui with a button that shall execute a method from a separate class when it is clicked. But when I click the button the following error comes up:

*** Process received signal** 
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: (nil)
[ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x113d0)[0x7fc1957ff3d0]
 **End of error message ***

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()   
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.ui.show()

class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

       @pyqtSlot()            
       def funcA(self):

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        gui = MyWindow()
        H = A()
        gui.connect(gui.button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), H.funcA) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What would be the correct way to connect the GUI elements with the methods that shall be executed?

Comment: You should read about new style signals and slots: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html. They are much more reliable than the old style, and they are easier to implement also. Basically, just connect a signal to a slot like this (button for example): `myButton.clicked.connect(mySlot)`

Comment: The code that you posted is full of errors. Please post a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the segfault with your code on my system, but it must be because your are  not 
keeping references to the objects that are supposed to live till the end of Qt app.

In `Main.__init__` you assign newly created `MyWindow` and `A` to local variables. These objects will be destroyed by the garbage collector
after `__init__` exits so the signal gets connected to a slot of a nonexistent object and this will lead to various nasty things including segfault.

To fix this you have two options:

**(Option1)** save these object as `Main`'s attributes:

```
    self.gui = MyWindow()
    self.H  = A()
```

**(Option2)** insert them in Qt's object tree by passing self in parent argument of their constructors

```
    gui = MyWindow(self)
```

Here is the code that works for me:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    # (Option2) Notice that the added `parent` argument is passed to super().__init__
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.show()

class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()            
    def funcA(self):
       print 'funcA'

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        # (Option1)
        self.H = A()

        # (Option2)
        gui = MyWindow(self)

        gui.button.clicked.connect(self.H.funcA)
        # gui.connect(gui.button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.H.funcA) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # the Main object must be saved from the garbage collector too
    main_dlg = Main()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```